# Upload image to FaceBook from SDCard

Tags: android, facebook

With Android 2.1 how can I upload an image on to a Facebook wall? The images are store in SDCard.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Facebook API http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android.
And then use this code:

```
 byte[] data = null;
 try {
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_FILE);
     Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
     data = baos.toByteArray();  
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
     e.printStackTrace();
     Log.d("onCreate", "debug error  e = " + e.toString());
  }     

     Bundle params = new Bundle(); 
     params.putString("method", "photos.upload");  
     params.putByteArray("picture", data);

     Facebook facebook = new Facebook(FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
     AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
     mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new RequestListener() {

        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
            Log.d("request RequestListener", "debug onMalformedURLException");
        }

        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            Log.d("request RequestListener", "debug onIOException");
        }

        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
            Log.d("request RequestListener", "debug onFileNotFoundException");
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            Log.d("request RequestListener", "debug onFacebookError");
        }

        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
             Log.d("request RequestListener", "debug onComplete");
        }
     }, null);
```

Be sure you application has permission to internet and sdcard reading