# Post image on facebook wall

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-intent, android-asynctask

I have been looking for posting image on facebook wall since morning and googled it, got much info about posting BUT no luck for me. I can post link without any errors but once I try for image getting NullPointer exception

After my button click event listener im calling this method. If I uncomment link params then it will display a dialog for asking share and cancel and If I put `params.putByteArray("picture", data);` this code I will get below logcat errors

```
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.m2fpremiun.dressup/com.m2fpremiun.dressup.FBProjectActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2189)
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2216)
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5000)
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:132)
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:50)
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at com.facebook.android.Util.encodeUrl(Util.java:85)
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.dialog(Facebook.java:774)
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at com.m2fpremiun.dressup.FBProjectActivity.postToWall(FBProjectActivity.java:436)
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at com.m2fpremiun.dressup.FBProjectActivity.loginToFacebook(FBProjectActivity.java:288)
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at com.m2fpremiun.dressup.FBProjectActivity.onCreate(FBProjectActivity.java:83)
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
09-15 15:51:50.647: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     ... 11 more
```

Please anybody help me to get solve this.

```
public void postToWall() {
    // post on user's wall.
    byte[] data = null;
     Bundle params = new Bundle();   
      //postParams.putString("description","I'm playing JackPac and Scored "+hScore+" ! Can you beat my High Score?");

     // postParams.putString("link", "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobi2fun.jackpac&hl=en");


      Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/sdcard0/Game/test.png");

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();              
        bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);              
        data = baos.toByteArray();                

        params.putString("caption", "Image Post");
        //params.putString("description","I'm playing XYZ Game and Scored "+hScore+" ! Can you beat my High Score?");
        //params.putString("link", "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xyz.package&hl=en");

        params.putString("method", "photos.upload"); 
        params.putByteArray("picture", data);
        facebook.dialog(this, "feed",params, new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            logoutFromFacebook();
            try {
                //facebook.logout(getApplicationContext());
                //facebook.setAccessExpires(0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            logoutFromFacebook();
            try {
            //  facebook.logout(getApplicationContext());
                mAsyncRunner.logout(getApplicationContext(),new RequestListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object         state) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }


    });
```

}

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

these permisions I have given in menifest file

I have checked this links and tried all codeBUT no luck [Facebook wall post with text and image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198025/facebook-wall-post-with-text-and-image)
[Upload image to FaceBook from SDCard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658877/upload-image-to-facebook-from-sdcard)

Comment: check this line java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.m2fpremiun.dressup/com.m2fpremiun.dressup.FBProjectActivity

Comment: Yes I have checked it, this is for null pointer exception on this line  params.putByteArray("picture", data); if I remove this line every thing will running fine BUT I need to post image on facebook wall

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for share text and image on facebook wall. It's works. It may be helpful to you.Try this.

Call facebooksharing method from your oncreate method as shown in bellow code. you can call it from where you want.

```html
CallbackManager callbackManager;
private LoginManager manager;

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
  setContentView(R.layout.Your_layout);
  callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

  //call method for sharing post
  FaceBookSharing();
}

public void FaceBookSharing() {
List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
 manager = LoginManager.getInstance();
 manager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissionNeeds);

 manager.registerCallback(callbackManager,
  new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
   @Override
   public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
    PostImage();
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancel() {
    System.out.println("onCancel");
   }

   @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
    System.out.println("onError");
   }
 });
}
private void PostImage() {
 Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    R.drawable.ic_launcher);

 SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image)
    .setCaption("Hey this is Demo post!")
    .build();

 SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhoto(
    photo).build();

 ShareApi.share(content, null);
 Toast.makeText(this, "Succsesfully posted on your wall", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
 .show(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Harvi Sirja.. But what is wrong with my code.. if I google about posting images same code will be displaying BUT my code is only not running. Can u please check with my code?